# How to write python dictionary of dataframes to separate excel workbooks

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a python dict that has 3 dataframes using the following code:

```
dict_of_dfs = {

    ID: group_df 

    for ID, group_df in df.groupby('ID') 

}
```

I can write the dataframes into 3 worksheets in one workbook using:

```
book = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Book1.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Book1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
for group_df, ID in dict_of_dfs.items():
        ID.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=group_df, index=False)

writer.save()
```

**Expected result**: I want to write each of the 3 dataframes to 3 separate excel ***workbooks***. How can this be done?

Comment: why not use `to_excel` function of the dataframe?

Comment: `for ID, group_df in dict_of_dfs.items(): group_df.to_excel(f'{ID}.xlsx')` ?.

Comment: I tried using: for ID, group_df in dict_of_dfs.items(): group_df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Desktop\{ID}.xlsx') and it created only 1 file titled {ID}.xlsx with only the last dataframe.

Comment: It's not `r'{ID}.xlsx`, should be `rf'C:\Users\...\{ID}.xlsx'`.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much! Now my next task is figuring out how to email those 3 files to specific email addresses that are stored in the dataframe.